# instagram realtime API

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm using [instagram realtime API](https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/), in order to get a specific user's posts I need to ask the user to register my app, right? But could you please let me know how a user can register my app?

This is the documentation:

> Subscriptions You may subscribe to real-time updates from four basic
>   Instagram object types:
>
> Users: receive notifications when users who have registered with your
>   application post new photos.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please refer https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/ documentation

After then call API of register as per requirement

```
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT-ID' \
     -F 'client_secret=CLIENT-SECRET' \
     -F 'object=user' \
     -F 'aspect=media' \
     -F 'verify_token=myVerifyToken' \
     -F 'callback_url=http://YOUR-CALLBACK/URL' \
     https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/
```